# Grails benchmarks compared to other web MVC platform (Rails, Django, ASP MVC)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, grails, benchmarking

I have been searching the web for recent benchmarks measuring **Grails** overall performance compared to its competitors (Rails, Django, ASP.NET MVC...), but I didn't find anything more recent than a  3 years-old article with obsolete grails version (0.5). See [here](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2007/03/23/rails-and-grails-performance-compared/) and [here](http://grails.org/Grails+vs+Rails+Benchmark).

So, starting from grails 1.2, are there any more recent grails benchmarks you are aware of ?

Or do you have your own performance tests for grails (compared to others if possible) ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any new benchmarks but unless you have some very specific needs Grails will most likely be more than good enough for you. The design choices you make while creating your application will affect it more than weather you use Grails, Rails, or PHP. For a list of public sites using Grails see [this](http://www.grails.org/Success+Stories)
See the comments on [this](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2008/10/03/sky-tv-sites-now-all-built-with-grails/) In particular

"tv.sky.com, movies.sky.com, showbiz.sky.com, sky1.sky.com all run off the same codebase just styled differently and different modules on each page. These
four sites in a month get around 110 million hits in total.

They essentially have 4 production nodes that sit behind a load balancer and a cdn. Since the site is so read heavy compared to write heavy we cache as
much stuff up the stack as possible. That means we use our CDN pretty extensively as well as caching at the load balancer. Those 4 web boxes are all vm’s
that point to a cluster of 2 postgres db’s vms. We have one node that isn’t available to the outside that is used for our rich publishing system that the
editors use."